# Getting before first string occurence

Tags: regex

Given a string, say

> prod175100210_cat40510788__

I want only the substring before first `_cat` which is `prod175100210`

But when I use the following regex

```
prod.*[^_]
```

I don't get the expected result.

What should be legit regex for extracting only before first `_cat`?

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: @e0k, Just simple sublime.

Comment: Many text processing tools and programming & scripting languages use some kind of regular expression syntax, each with slightly different features and format. Specifying which one you are using is helpful. See the [regex tag information](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prod[^_]*
```

Where `[^_]*` means: *zero or more characters that are not an underscore*.

Comment: Out of "abc_cd_prod175100210_cat40510788__/p.prod?icid=&searchType=EndecaDrivenCat&rte=%252F" What it will match ? I want only prod175100210 to match.

Comment: @Dracowane: if you want a good answer, take the time to write a clear and good question.

Comment: @Dracowane: It's correct, show your code why it's wrong

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte So this one will select prod? also.

Comment: @Tim007 Check my above comment

Comment: @Dracowane: Did you try? prod[\d]+

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a mid-string match for a substring starting with `prod` and ending with `_` you can do:

```
(prod[^_]+)_
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jQ5wU6/1)